# Bijectivity and partial functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is injective, surjective but partial, will it still be bijective or does the partiality necessarily implies the bigger cardinality of the domain?

Comment: well the function is indeed partially bijective

Comment: But then X will not have the same cardinality of Y, even though f is bijective. Isn't it?

Comment: note that the function is **partially** bijective, for example let $f(x)$ be $x^2$ for $x\le1$ and $x$ for $x>1$, then this function is partially bijective (duo to identity function), but clearly is not bijective over the whole of its domain, for example you can find two points of the domain such that the value for both of them is $4$, hence the function is not injective and so is not bijective, (check and see that the function is not also surjective).

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, the restriction of the function to its domain is a bijection between its domain and its codomain.